# Does hair grow faster in the sun?

Tags: environmental-health, hair, sun-exposure

I've been told that hair grows faster when you are in the sun, is there any truth to that or is it a myth among people in a sun starved country? :)

> **Related:**
>
> - [Does plucking/epilation impact hair growth?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3058/does-plucking-impact-hair-growth)
> - [If you shave or wax, will the hair  grow back stronger or thicker?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/490/is-it-true-that-if-you-shave-or-wax-your-legs-the-hair-will-grow-stronger-thick)

Answer (score 3):

[This paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16311170) indicates that although sun can't hurt the hair shaft, some people use hair sun-screens to reduce damage (perhaps from bleaching?) to the hair.  It also notes that any damage done to the hair shaft itself is replaced by new hair growth.

[This paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19158839) studies the effect of ultraviolet radiation on the hair follicle (the part that the hair actually grows out of) and indicates that UV radiation is detrimental to the health of the hair follicle.

Studies say: wear a hat :)