# Does shaving your beard more frequently make it grow faster?

Tags: medical-science, physiology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If you shave or wax, will the hair grow back stronger or thicker?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/490/if-you-shave-or-wax-your-legs-will-the-hair-grow-stronger-thicker-or-similar)

Some of my friends seem to have the same impression. Shaving daily your face seems to make hair grow faster compared to shave it only every 3-4 days. Is this kind of self-deception (short hair grows nonlinearly faster then longer one) and if thats the case, is there a psychology term for this phenomenon. Or do pre and after shave chemicals maybe have a influence on hair growth?

Comment: Did you see [THIS](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/490/if-you-shave-or-wax-your-legs-will-the-hair-grow-stronger-thicker-or-similar)? Seems at least related.

Comment: I've made the older question more general, as the answer it received was about all kinds of hair anyway and closed this one as a duplicate.