# Does cutting or shaving the hair of infants cause better hair regrowth?

Tags: physiology, hair

An earlier Skeptics Stack Exchange question asks: [If you shave or wax, will the hair  grow back stronger or thicker?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/490/if-you-shave-or-wax-will-the-hair-grow-back-stronger-or-thicker)

However, I am interesting in a more specific claim: that shaving the head of an infant will lead to thicker and stronger hair later. For example, this is discussed at [babycenter.com](http://www.babycenter.com/404_is-it-true-that-shaving-a-babys-head-or-cutting-his-hair-ver_10303163.bc).

Does shaving of hairs of an infant really promote hair growth and better quality new hair?

The [BMJ web-site reports](http://www.bmj.com/content/335/7633/1288) an answer for adults, but I have been unable to follow the references to see if they are applicable to infants.

Many of the comments give reasons that the hair is dead and, hence, it does not matter whether you cut it or not, but I see there are many confounding variables e.g. the weight of hair may have some effect on the follicle. The weight reduction is more prominent in infants. Also, the pulling action affects the delicate hair follicle of infants.

Comment: I think this is a good question but you will fare better here if you demonstrate where the claim is being made by finding an example of where someone makes the claim and linking to it.

Comment: Although not providing references is a "Taboo" here on skeptics, some claims are widespread enough to not require a reference, IMHO. Such as this one. Skeptics is about checking claims people believe in, people DO believe that cutting hair makes it thicker.

Comment: One possible explanation of "Ever since cutting it, he's always had a beautiful head..." is the fact that the hair will *look* better after being trimmed. See my answer.

Comment: Putting the question on hold while we decide if it is a duplicate.

Comment: There is a [very closely related question](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/490/if-you-shave-or-wax-will-the-hair-grow-back-stronger-or-thicker) which I believe will have the same answer, so we can close this as a duplicate. However, this one specifically mentions infants, so it could be argued is a different question (but should be edited to make more specific). Ali, are you happy with the answers in the other question?

Comment: @Oddthinking No, this question should be only about infants ,adults are much different than Infants to the extent we have paedratics . I its more specific as it asks about scalp area hair only. I am not satisfied with the answers there too,

Comment: there are many confounding variables in this which makes it inconclusive to give a judgement. eg weight of hair reduces due to cutting hence may have some effect on the follicle. Thie weight reduction is more prominent in infants . Besides the pulling action also affects the delicate hair follicle of infants.

Comment: I doubt this will be answerable; there are unlikely to be studies specific to infants, but I am ready to be surprised.

Comment: @Oddthinking We wouldn't need a study specific to infants. A description of the mechanism of hair growth and evidence that this is the same regardless of age would be sufficient.

Comment: @Ali You've said in several places that "the weight of hair may have some effect on the follicle", but I haven't found a single reference that suggests this may be the case. All references I can find say that weight does not affect the follicle's activity.

Comment: @Articuno: Ali seems to be speculating that there *may* be some, as yet identified, factor that makes the general case unable to be applied to this specific case, and therefore the general case should be treated with suspicion. Hence my conclusion that it would require an (IMO unlikely) specific study.